# Laravel 5 view layout template

Tags: laravel-5

i want to migrate a system from laravel 4 to laravel 5,
the original code are

```
$this->layout->body = View::make('user.login');
```

is it laravel 5 no longer using `viewL=::make`?
how shoud i rewrite this?

Comment: View::make() still works fine in Laravel 5.  Are you seeing a particular error?  It may be that you're having namespace trouble because controllers are usually namespaced in Laravel 5.  Maybe try adding "use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;" to the top of your controller file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Jad mentioned in his answer, you can user `view('users.login')` to get a View instance for that view asset. You can then call the [`render()`](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/View/View.html#method_render) method to get the string returned from the view.

Your code might look something like this:

```
$this->layout->body = view('user.login')->render();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just `view('users.login');`

Comment: actually i want to set the layout body to that view only, but i cant manage to do it like old ways.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 4 the BaseController has the `setUpLayout()` method that sets up the `$this->layout` property. If you are using Laravel 5 you might want to implement the method your self and make sure its called so you have access to the `$this->layout` property from the controllers.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this in your controller function

```
return view ('dashboard.index')->with([
'title' => 'homepage',
'layout' => 'layout.master'
]);
```

and catch the layout in view like this

```
@extends($layout)
```

that's so simple way